# Google play store reject my update by wrong version

Tags: permissions, google-play, location

I uploaded my appbundle Version 2 to google play store. That one was reject due to I accidently added background location permission.

I removed this permission request, and finally Version 14 is online for sale.

I made an update Version 15. But it is rejected twice. And the reason is, Version 2 requests background location.

BTW, Version 2 is at Open Test session, but the track is paused. I don't know where I can remove it.

But anyway, I don't know why my version 15 can be rejected twice by the reason from Version 2. I tried to contact them, but I still haven't got a reply for a week.

Version 15 rejection note in Google play console:
[image]

Permissions that Version 15 required shown in google play:
[image]

Rejection email:
[image]

Comment: Put the fixed version in all tracks you use/have used

Comment: Hmmmm, sounds like a good idea.... Let me try!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is:

Though my bundle file doesn't request background location permission, in "App Content/Sensitive app permissions" session, I declared I have background location. After I declared "No", I got it passed quickly.

Some reviewers just see if my app requires this permission, some of them look to App Content. That's why I sometimes got rejected, sometimes got approved.